# How to hide the entries in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, ejs

Trying to stop display of certain params into datatable.

Already used `Info: false`. However still the datatable shows Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#cli').addClass('hide');
    $('.users8').addClass('activetab');

    var oTable = $("#bugtable").dataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "Info" : false,
        "paging":false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "autoWidth": false,
        "columns": [{
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }, {
            "width": "10%"
        }]
    });

    $('#addfor').keyup(function() {
        oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the property sEmptyTable in oLanguage when setting your table to an empty string:

```
var oTable= $('#bugtable').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": ""
    }
    // Other table setup options
}
```